# How to make Toggle button programmatically On & OFF in Android?

Tags: android, togglebutton

I need to make Toggle button programmatically **On** & **OFF**.

Answer (score 27):

You can use `toggleButton.setChecked(true or false)` method to make Toggle button programmatically On & OFF.

Answer (score 7):

It's so simple inside your layout file

```
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/ToggleButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="Off Stage"
    android:textOn="On Stage"/>
```

and in Java

```
ToggleButton  tglbtn = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.Id.ToggleButton01);

tglbtn.setChecked(false);
```

Comment: Worked for `Switch` too.

Answer (score 5):

Try `toggleButton.setSelected(true)` & `toggleButton.setSelected(false)`

It will make toggle on & off.

This will make the  toggle to true or false. U can use `toggleButton.toggle();` to change from one state to other.

Comment: `setSelected()` doesn't change the toggle state. According to google it does the following: `Changes the selection state of this view. A view can be selected or not. Note that selection is not the same as focus. Views are typically selected in the context of an AdapterView like ListView or GridView; the selected view is the view that is highlighted.`

Answer (score 2):

Try ToggleButton. It has a `.toggle()` method to switch the states.

Answer (score 1):

in xml file

```
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/ToggleButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOff="Off Stage"
    android:textOn="On Stage"/>
```

in java file

```
ToggleButton tglbtn;
    tglbtn=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);
    tglbtn.toggle();
```

this idea also you can try

```
 tglbtn.setSelected(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change both the state and the UI of a toggle button you need to implement two functions:

```
toggle.setChecked(Boolean value)
toggle.setSelected(Boolean value)
```

setChecked() sets the intrinsic boolean associated with the view object and setSelected sets the UI.

Answer (score 0):

To Toggle set and get value use the following

```
togg=toggleButton.getText().toString();
    // Get the default value off 
     String off =mo.getOn();
    if (off.equals("OFF")){
    holder.toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }else{
    holder.toggleButton.setChecked(true);
    }
```